# Content with non embedded links: is that worth an edit/is that a trivial edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

Often I see content such as what I see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/41017/29318) in 2 answers with raw links. I personally find it visually offensive. Often people may not know about the link tool in the editor, or think they have to use some markup...

In such cases, can I edit to embed - is that a trivial edit? Or should I just leave a comment for the contributor to do so himself?

Answer (score 2):

I'm fine with these kinds of edits, I agree that links like that should be marked up properly.

As far as being too trivial, my personal policy is as long as a decent effort was made to correct any glaring errors in the post, I'll approve the suggested edit. That includes obvious spelling errors, typos, image alt text, or markdown formatting.

I don't expect everyone to catch every error; I'm more likely to improve an edit if I catch something that may have been missed rather than reject the edit.

Comment: Thank you! I believe in different people different strokes in that it also applies to editing i.e. to echo your last paragraph. It's a process. There is also an aspect which I didn't allude to which is that embedding sort of weakens the possibility for advertisement. A domain name in content has an impact imho. Thanks again.

Comment: I always try to edit these links. For aesthetic reasons, but also because as you mention links are no follow but addresses not.